# Why Spring MessageSource arguments are not filled correctly in some locales?

Tags: spring, internationalization, arguments, double-quotes

```
mailconfirm.mail.body=<html><body><h3 style="margin: 0 0 1em;">Hi, {0}!</h3>\
    To confirm your email address click on the confirmation link given bellow. If clicking on the link doesn't work, copy and paste the link in a new browser tab. <br /><br />\
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/confirm_email.html?action=activate&hash={1}">http://www.domain.com/confirm_email.html?action=activate&hash={1}</a><br /><br />\
    Kind regards,<br />\
    Your Something
    </body></html>
```

This above is the particular message used for the code bellow.

```
String country = "AU";
Object[] args = new Object[] { account.getLogin(), confirm.getHash() };

helper.setText(appContext.getMessage("mailconfirm.mail.body", args,
                new Locale(country)), true);
```

I debugged both arguments and they both have the right values. When debuging `appContext.getMessage` line, I saw that the `{1}` param is not filled with correct value however `{0}` is.

Any ideas what could be wrong? I suspect it could be some locale issue.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Issue solved!
It appears that the problem was because the message mailconfirm.mail.body contained an apostrophe somewhere after {0} and between {1}. After replaced `doesn't` with `does not` it fixed the problem. I didn't know apostrophes can't be used in there. 
P.S. Is it a bug or just my mistake and apostrophes should be escaped?

```
mailconfirm.mail.body=<html><body><h3 style="margin: 0 0 1em;">Hi, {0}!</h3>\
    To confirm your email address, click on the confirmation link given bellow. If clicking on the link doesn't work, copy and paste the link in a new browser tab. <br /><br />\
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/confirm_email.html?action=activate&hash={1}">http://www.domain.com/confirm_email.html?action=activate&hash={1}</a><br /><br />\
    Kind regards,<br />\
    Your Something
    </body></html>
```

One `doesn't` took me about an hour to figure it out and push a fix. Hahaha.. From now on I consider apostrophes being evil!

Comment: Hooray!  Because you spent an hour on this I didn't have to.  Also, it turns out that you can get your single quotes to work properly by doubling them, like `''`.  This will render as a single quote, and it will also play nicely with MessageSource arguments.  But confusingly, this *only* works in property strings that have parameters, otherwise it will result in both apostrophes being displayed.

Comment: This link may be useful to better understand what is going on: http://blog.pfa-labs.com/2010/07/infamous-dissapearing-single-quote-in.html

Comment: same for http://www.mscharhag.com/2013/10/single-quote-escaping-in-java-resource.html and the `ResourceBundleMessageSource`'s `alwaysUseMessageFormat` flag

Comment: note: if you're going to copy/paste the above mailconfirm.mail.body..... be sure to change the doesn't -> does not.... I spent 30 min ironically trouble shooting this haha.

Comment: Saved me hours and more hours of researching and failing miserably...THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 44):

Spring's `ResourceBundleMessageSource` (which I think you are using) uses `MessageFormat` for replacing placeholders (`{0}`) inside messages. `MessageFormat` requires that single quotes (`'`) are escaped using two single quotes (`''`) (see: [MessageFormat Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)).

However, by default messages that do not contain any arguments will not be parsed by `MessageFormat`. So single quotes in messages without arguments don't need to be escaped.

`ResourceBundleMessageSource` provides a flag called `alwaysUseMessageFormat` that can be used if `MessageFormat` should be applied to all messages. So a single quote need always be escaped by two single quotes.

See this [blog post](http://www.mscharhag.com/2013/10/single-quote-escaping-in-java-resource.html) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

I am not able to convince my business team to add double apos in required places and some times they are forgetting also.
So I just overrided `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource#loadProperties` as :
if the value contains, `"'"` & `"{0"`, then replace the `"'"` with `"''"` and put in to the Properties with the same key.

Comment: Yes, it is important to add double ' , ' in your messages.properties. Example: user.locked = Votre compte a \u00E9t\u00E9 bloqu\u00E9 parce que vous avez saisis {0} fois de suite un mauvais mot de passe. Ce blocage s''effectue pendant {1} minutes.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use `String.format`, change the `{X}` for `%s`.

```
mailconfirm.mail.body=<html><body><h3 style="margin: 0 0 1em;">Hi, %s!</h3>\
    To confirm your email address click on the confirmation link given bellow. If clicking on the link doesn't work, copy and paste the link in a new browser tab. <br /><br />\
    <a href="http://www.domain/confirm_email.html?action=activate&hash=%s">http://www.domain/confirm_email.html?action=activate&hash=%s</a><br /><br />\
    Kind regards,<br />\
    Your Something
    </body></html>


String whatEver = messageSource.getMessage("mailconfirm.mail.body", null, locale);

whatEver = String.format(whatEver,account.getLogin(), confirm.getHash() );
```

Hope it's useful.