# Argument to message in properties file not being resolved by Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties-file, thymeleaf

I have the following key/message in a properties file:

```
kadjoukor.registration.form.successMessage=You've been successfully registered. An email has been sent to <b>{0}</b>. Please activate your registration by consulting your email.
```

In my template, I try to display it as follows in a Thymeleaf template:

```
<div id="alert-success" th:if="${#bools.isTrue(member)}" class="alert alert-success" th:utext="#{kadjoukor.registration.form.successMessage(${member.email})}"></div>
```

All I get is:

```
Youve been successfully registered. An email has been sent to {0}. Please activate your registration by consulting your email.
```

Notice the argument has not been replaced by its value i.e. I get this: **{0}**. Also notice the apostrophe has been removed by Spring...

**EDIT:**
Here is how I've configured the message source:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="/META-INF/i18n/application,/META-INF/i18n/messages" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to prevent this problem, the apostrophe **has to be escaped by another apostrophe**.

See: [Why Spring MessageSource arguments are not filled correctly in some locales?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332378/why-spring-messagesource-arguments-are-not-filled-correctly-in-some-locales)

However, note that this **only occurs when there's one or several arguments** in the message.